# Could someone explain how this passed function is returned and called? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, return, closures, this

I was reading an article on wrapping functions, and came across this example, which shows how you can wrap a function to determine its performance.

```
function profile(func, funcName) {
  return function () {
    var start = new Date(),
      returnVal = func.apply(this, arguments),
      end = new Date(),
      duration = stop.getTime() - start.getTime();

    console.log(`${funcName} took ${duration} ms to execute`);
    return returnVal;
  };
}

var profiledMax = profile(Math.max, 'Math.max');
profiledMax.call(Math, 1, 2);
// => "Math.max took 2 ms to execute"
```

I'm confused because of these lines:

```
returnVal = func.apply(this, arguments),
```

and:

```
return returnVal;
```

The way I'm looking at it, when you call profile(Math.max...), that will return an anonymous function, so how come that anonymous function can be called with arguments? I would have thought that you would need to return and then call that anonymous function, to access the returnVal, which is also a function? Like this:

```
var profiledMax = profile(Math.max, 'Math.max');
var moreProfiledMax = profiledMax();
moreProfiledMax.call(Math, 1,2)
```

Comment: The returned anonymous function carries the arguments that will be passed to the function you want to test (profiledMax stores this returned function, so when you call profiledMax, the function receives the arguments). By doing `returnVal = func.apply(this, arguments)`, the code calls `func` with the context (this) and all the arguments that you will provide when you call it. It stores the result of the execution in `returnVal` so that the returned function can return the same value as the one you want to test. Beware, there seems to have errors, you define `end` var and use `stop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it's very simple, first you got this function which wrap another function

```
function profile(func, funcName) {
  return function () {
    var start = new Date()**;**
      returnVal = func.apply(this, arguments)**;**
      end = new Date()**;**
      duration = stop.getTime() - start.getTime();

    console.log(`${funcName} took ${duration} ms to execute`);
    return returnVal;
  };
}
```

this line:

```
var profiledMax = profile(Math.max, 'Math.max');
```

execute the outter function passing it arguments that will be saved in the scope of the inner function that the outter function defines. And finally the inner function is returned as if you had:

```
 var profiledMax =  function () {
        var start = new Date();
          returnVal = **Math.max**.apply(this, arguments);
          end = new Date();
          duration = stop.getTime() - start.getTime();

        console.log(`${funcName} took ${duration} ms to execute`);
        return returnVal;
      }
```

and then this line:

```
profiledMax.call(Math, 1, 2);
```

executes `profiledMax` passing it 2 arguments (you can pass arguments to any function in JS) and binding the `this` keyword to Math object as if this function was executed:

```
function () {
    var start = new Date(),
      returnVal = Math.max.apply(**Math**, arguments),
      end = new Date(),
      duration = stop.getTime() - start.getTime();

    console.log(`${funcName} took ${duration} ms to execute`);
    return returnVal;
  };
```

the problem with your proposal is when you do this: `var moreProfiledMax = profiledMax();` `returnVal = func.apply(this, arguments);` will break, because func won't exist in the scope.

Comment: Thankyou, splitting it out definitely helps. One last question then, why is 'return returnVal' needed?

Comment: you are welcome! Indeed returning the returnVal is not relevant in your case :)

Answer (score 1):

`returnVal` is not a function, but is the result of calling `func`. The `apply` method will execute the method, unlike `bind` which will return a function.